# Can I remove items from my App Store updates

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, pages, keynote, numbers

The App Store wants me to update my Pages 4.3 to Pages 5.0.

Given the changes to and reviews of Pages 5.0, I wish to stay with 4.3.

Can I somehow delete the upgrade reminder from the list?

I would also like to remove the Keynote and Numbers upgrade reminders as well.

---

**Note that** my current Pages, Numbers and Keynote were purchased on CD's and not via the App Store.  As such, they do not show up on my purchases list in the App Store.

Answer (score 4):

Your old iWork versions are not removed, so you can safely upgrade and keep both versions.

As Apple rolls "upgrades" to the newer version back in you can decide when it has restored sufficient functionality for it to do what you need it to.

Sorry if this doesn't specifically answer your question but it will get rid of the updates reminder...

Answer (score 1):

If others search for how to disable automatic updates for an application downloaded from App Store, you can hide the application from the Purchases tab. (Secondary-click the application and select Hide Purchase.)